# Perl: Open a file from a URL

Tags: perl

I wanted to know how to open a file from a URL rather than a local file and I found the following answer on another thread:

```
use IO::String;
my $handle = IO::String->new(get("google.com"));
my @lines = <$handle>;                       
close $handle;
```

This works perfectly... on my PC...

But when I transferred the code over to my hosted server it complains that it can't find the IO module.  So is there another way to open a file from an URL, that doesn't require any external modules (or uses one that is pretty much installed on every server)...?

Comment: The module `IO::String` provides very specific functionality.  Are you sure that you need that?  What do you mean by "_open a file from an URL_" -- do you have a particular reason to use file-style operations? There are many ways to retrieve and manage content from Internet. What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: I've re-opened this question. It's certainly not a duplicate of the question that people suggested. It looked like a duplicate because it appears the OP went off on the wrong track in looking for a solution.

Comment: `my $handle = IO::String->new(get("google.com")); my @lines = <$handle>;` is utterly pointless.

Comment: problem solved. the hosting company just (unexpectedly) installed the module.  And I'm not sure why you think it's pointless, as it does exactly what I want it to do... reads a .csv file in from a 3rd party website into an array.

Comment: @jxm: If you just want the lines in an array, then  the filehandle part of your code is completely unnecessary. You just want: `my @lines = split /\n/, get($url);`

Comment: ok, that also seems to work (if I take the split out). thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to "open a file from a URL" as you ask. Well, I suppose you could throw something together using the [`progress()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#progress) callback from LWP::UserAgent, but even then I don't think it would work how you want it to.

But you can make something that looks like it's doing what you want pretty easily. Actually, what we're really doing is pulling all the data back from the URL and then opening a filehandle on a string that contains that data.

```
use LWP::Simple;

my $data = get('https://google.com');
open my $url_fh, '<', \$data or die $!;

# Now $url_fh is a filehandle wrapped around your data.
# Treat it like any other filehandle.

while (<$url_fh>) {
  print;
}
```

Your problem was that IO::String wasn't installed. But there's no need to install it, as it's simple enough to do what it does with standard Perl features (simply open a filehandle on a reference to a string).

**Update:** IO::String is completely unnecessary here. Not only because you can do what it does very simply, by just opening a filehandle on a reference to your string, but also because all you want to do is to read a file from a web site into an array. And in that case, your code is simply:

```
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'something';
my @records = split /\n/, get($url);
```

You might even consider adding some error handing.

```
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'something';
my $data = get($url);
die "No data found\n" unless defined $data;
my @array = split /\n/, get($url);
```

Comment: Actually LEONT wrote https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::http a few years back, which lets you simply `open` a URL. But OP wouldn't have that installed on their shared hosting either I guess.

Comment: Thanks, that does what I need and gets rid of the IO:string problem

Answer (score 7):

You can install [PerlIO::http](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::http), which will give you an input layer for opening a filehandle from a URL via `open`. This thing is not included in the Perl core, but it [will work with Perls as early as 5.8.9](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=PerlIO-http%200.004).

Once you've installed it, all you need to do is `open` with a layer `:http` in the mode argument. There is nothing to `use` here. That happens automatically.

```
open my $fh, '<:http', 'https://metacpan.org/recent';
```

You can then read from `$fh` like a regular file. Under the hood it will take care of getting the data over the wire.

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) { ... }
```